# How to integrate Google Home/Amazon Echo with Arduino/Pi?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, alexa-skills-kit, google-home, amazon-echo

I want integrate a voice assistant and a Raspberry Pi and/or Arduino for some projects. I'm looking for information on how to actually achieve this. I'm unfamiliar with how integrating these works, but I'd like to avoid having to use external servers if at all possible.

I'm looking for links or material from which I can start learning. I want to start with simple light control, but would also like to try motor/servo control. Where should I start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't really any good ways to connect Google Home or Amazon Echo directly to a device, or vice versa. They themselves rely on outside servers to do most of their work, and integrate with other services to interface with devices. Most of the common DIY projects use something like IFTTT to accomplish this. I myself did it using Home Assistant, but that is a comprehensive and very involved road. I might suggest checking out these projects for ideas:

1. https://www.hackster.io/phpoc_man/google-home-control-diy-devices-3be448
2. https://hackaday.com/2017/05/23/google-home-meets-esp8266/
3. http://tinkerman.cat/using-google-assistant-control-your-esp8266-devices/